# Replacing string in all files found by grep. Can't get it to work

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, perl

I find all needed files with grep: `grep --include=\*.{php,ini,conf,sh} -ril -P "'([\d\w\-\_\.]+)(@domain.com)'" '/var/www_data/somepath/'`

Now I assume it's either use of sed or perl to for replacement process, alas I can't figure out how to use above regexp in either of them.
I saw [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471192/1260286) and [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721349/1260286) but as I said, I couldn't get it work with my pattern (and by that I mean that I get > in the next line after executing command. I assume it's problem with regexp shown above when used with sed or perl), so any advice on that matter would be nice.

Also, I don't know if it's possible (it's not really important) but I'd like to print some string for each file in with replacement occurred, for example `File fixed: /path/to/file/` (file names taken from grep list maybe?)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? (P.S. yes `sed` and `perl` can be used to search and replace. Not `grep`.)

Comment: Yeah, I know grep is not for replacements, just for search. I'm just trying to replace all email addresses under certain domain which are listed in double single quotes in huge amount of files.

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32666. It uses `grep` and `xargs` to touch only files with a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you get a `>` in the next line after hitting, it means that one of your quotes isn't closed yet. I couldn't find that mistake in your regex. But you do not need to surround the path `/var/www_data/somepath/` with single quotes. I assume there are no unusual characters in `somepath`?

Anyways, I tested your regex with sed. `\d\w` look like `vim` syntax for me, that's why I translated it to ascii (which always works). Also, inside of `[]` you do not need to escape `.`:

```
sed -r "s/'([A-Za-z0-9_-.]+)(@domain.com)'/'adsf'/g" test.dat
```

Indeed you can use `sed` or `perl` for your task. You don't necessarily need `grep` to generate a file list, unless you have GB of data. Then presorting could result in a speed benefit.

To test your *regex*, you could do the following:

```
cd /var/www_data/somepath/
sed -r 's|pattern|replace-pattern|g' a_single_file.php
```

When you're satisfied with the result, just add the `-ibak` (`--in-place=bak`) argument and run it on all files

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -o -name '*.ini' -o name '*.conf' -o -name '*.sh' \
-exec sed -r -ibak 's|pattern|replace-pattern|g' '{}' \;
```

The original files are being put into `<orignalname.php>.bak`.

To answer your last question. For this job, `grep` is the tool you want, you could run it on the `.bak` files generated by sed above:

```
grep --recursive --include='*.bak' -E --files-with-matches 'pattern' . > files_fixed.txt
```

or, simply:

```
find . -type f -name '*.bak'
```

Comment: The `find` piped into `sed` messes with all the file times, and not just the files where the match occurs.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` you can use `sed -i`.

```
sed -i 'script' *.{php,ini,conf,sh}
```

Comment: `sed` messes with all the file times, and not just the files where a match would occur from `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux:

```
sed -i 's#FIND#REPLACE#g' *.{php,ini,conf,sh}
```

On MacOS:

```
sed -i '' 's#FIND#REPLACE#g' *.{php,ini,conf,sh}
```

The sed in MacOS is expecting a backup parameter after -i, use empty string if you don't need backup files. The "g" is for global replace, otherwise it's only the first per row.

Comment: `sed` messes with all the file times, and not just the files where a match would occur from `grep`.